# how can i item search from zend service amazon in zend according to price range

Tags: zend-framework2

I want to search item at basis of price range from zend service amazon library while i have product search at keyword,title but not price range.

Answer (score 0):

In most categories you can search by `MinimumPrice` and `MaximumPrice`, see the Amazon [API docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01/DG/UKSearchIndexParamForItemsearch.html)